# Generate each combination of one item from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

I want to take an indeterminate number of lists, of indeterminate length, and generate each possible combination of one element from each list. For efficiencies' sake it is acceptable for my purposes to simply iterate over each combination, rather than store the results.

For example, the following list of lists:

```
[['A','B','C'],['w','x','y','z'],[1,2]]
```

Would become:

```
['A','w',1],['A','w',2],['A','x',1],['A','x',2],...,['C','z',1],['C','z',2]
```

Not quite a zip, not quite itertools.permutation()... It's easy to do this if you know ahead of time the number of lists, but in this situation I won't. I'm sure I can slap together a recursive solution to this, but perhaps this has already been solved. Any insight?

Comment: The way the question is asked and the title itself is better here; I could easily google this ("duplicate") question and answer, but I would never have found the "original" when looking for a quick solution to the exact same problem the OP had. Also, the answer is much more clear here, too.

Answer (score 10):

[itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is the right tool for you

```
>>> some_list = [['A','B','C'],['w','x','y','z'],[1,2]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*some_list))
[('A', 'w', 1), ('A', 'w', 2), ('A', 'x', 1), ('A', 'x', 2), ('A', 'y', 1), ('A', 'y', 2), ('A', 'z', 1), ('A', 'z', 2), ('B', 'w', 1), ('B', 'w', 2), ('B', 'x', 1), ('B', 'x', 2), ('B', 'y', 1), ('B', 'y', 2), ('B', 'z', 1), ('B', 'z', 2), ('C', 'w', 1), ('C', 'w', 2), ('C', 'x', 1), ('C', 'x', 2), ('C', 'y', 1), ('C', 'y', 2), ('C', 'z', 1), ('C', 'z', 2)]
```

Couple of key points

1. `itertools.product` expects the iterables as a parameter. So you need to use the `splat` operator to pass the list as arguments
2. itertools.product returns a generator. You need to convert it to a list, to dump the entire content. Alternatively you can iterate it or pass to a function with expects a iterable

   ```
   for e in itertools.product(*some_list):
       print e
   ```